# StackExchange global menu: Autofocus on text box upon typing, for immediate search

Tags: feature-request, search, menu-bar

When I click the "StackExchange" (left of top toolbar) to navigate to another SE community, I have to scroll down to the text box and click it, and only then I can search.

Feature requests:

1. (optional) Put the search textbox above "Your Communities".
2. When I start typing, set the cursor/focus automatically in the search box such that the search begins right away when I start typing.
3. Show results of "meta search" only when I start typing, so the custom community list would still be visible.

Comment: Stealing focus in that dropdown sounds like a rough user experience for *most* users. If you are visiting certain sites often, just add them to the list of "your communities" for easy access so you don't have to keep searching.

Comment: @AnnaLear stealing the focus wouldn't change any user experience except maybe the order of the menu.

Answer (score 1):

No. I prefer it as it's working now: first comes my own customized list of sites, and only then the rest of the sites.

Your way would force me to always search for the site I want or scroll down to the customized list, while now I can simply click it on first sight.

That said, auto focusing the search textbox when you reach it by scrolling would be something nice to have.

Comment: putting the search box above would only push down 1-2 of your communities, but you'll be able to see the rest...

Comment: @Sparkler nope, the search box is related to the "more stack exchange communities" and there are ~130 of them at the moment.

Comment: why not split them from each other then?

Comment: @Sparkler because it won't make sense: you search the whole list of sites, not the customized list. Unless you mean to add option to search your own list of sites when it contains more than certain amount of sites?

Comment: add a visual separator after the textbox if it bothers you. and I meant searching everything, including your own.

Comment: Sorry, still no sense to me, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: in short: everything stays the same from all aspects, except the textbox would be higher and would "steal" the focus.